# Ktor startup example errors

Tags: gradle, kotlin, ktor

I'm very new to Kotlin and Ktor and Gradle, wanted to try Ktor, so gone through the steps explained [here](http://ktor.io/getting-started-idea#start-a-project), and ended up with this code, and structure shown in the screenshot:

As seen there are lots of error, how to fix them?

```
package blog

import org.jetbrains.ktor.netty.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.routing.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.application.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.host.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.http.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.response.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("My Example Blog", ContentType.Text.Html)
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

The `build.gradle` file is auto generated as:

```
group 'Example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incomplete `build.gradle` script (missing dependencies) - see [here](http://ktor.io/getting-started-gradle) for details. Here's the good one:

```
group 'Example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
ext.ktor_version = '0.4.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-core:$ktor_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-netty:$ktor_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this error at running the app: "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation"

Comment: @HasanAYousef, this is rather not an error but a warning. You need to configure the logger as well.

Comment: Thanks @OPal, can you help me with the second step I want to do, in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365605/how-to-create-jar-create-executable-of-the-ktor-embedded-server

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [IntelliJ Ktor plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10823-ktor) to bootstrap your app. The `./gradlew run` script runs right out of the box with this configuration without you needing to fiddle with the Gradle configuration. It's the easiest way to get started.

Here is an example Ktor app that uses the configuration: https://gitlab.com/tinacious/ktor-example

If you'd like to run your application from IntelliJ, check out this answer for the run configuration I use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65350680/1870884

Comment: Alas, the plug in is now ​marked as Obsolete. (April 2021)

Comment: This is because it now comes bundled with IntelliJ.