# How to create .jar (Create Executable) of the Ktor embedded Server

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, ktor

I'm very new to Kotlin and Ktor and Gradle. Was able to create embedded server as explained in Ktor site, with the following code:

**BlogApp.kt**:

```
package blog

import org.jetbrains.ktor.netty.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.routing.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.application.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.features.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.host.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.http.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.response.*

fun Application.module() {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(Routing) {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("My Example Blog  sfs 122", ContentType.Text.Html)
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080, watchPaths = listOf("BlogAppKt"), module = Application::module).start()
}
```

and **build.gradle**:

```
group 'Example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
ext.ktor_version = '0.4.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-core:$ktor_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-netty:$ktor_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

The server run fine at: `localhost:8080`

and the I can see the below files in the `out` folder:

`C:\Users\Home\IdeaProjects\Example\out\production\classes\blog`

How can I know create an executable file .jar of this server, so I can distribute it to the user?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to do is to add the following piece of code to `build.gradle` file:

```
jar {
    baseName '<jar_name>'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'blog.BlogAppKt'
    }

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Then run: `gradle clean jar`. After it's finished navigate to: `build/libs` and run `java -jar <jar_name>.jar`.

Or run it using `javaw -jar <jar_name>.jar` instead of java (you might need to make sure its on the path if the JAVA_HOME is not defined well). This will run it without any console.

P.S. You can also use `application` plugin or `shadowJar`.

Comment: When I run it from IJ terminal, I got this error: 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: when I run it from cmd, I got this: * What went wrong:
Task 'clean' not found in root project 'blog'.

Comment: @HasanAYousef, are you sure you run it from correct location and have java and kotlin plugins applied?

Comment: Something looks to be wrong in my setup, once I used text editor and command line only, creating the files with `gradle init --type java-library` then creating my files, and compile them `gradle clean jar` everything gone smooth as you described.

Comment: @HasanAYousef, no idea what may caused the problem but I'm glad it works now!

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative version for `build.gradle.kts` (kotlin-based gradle file).

```
tasks.jar {
  // for the case if inside your project there is some duplicate
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
  manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "blog.BlogAppKt"
  configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
    from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
  }
  archiveBaseName.set(project.name + "-all")
}
```

The result is `./build/libs/${project.name}-all.jar` file.

For running:

```
java -jar ./build/libs/${project.name}-all.jar
```