# KTor site not reachable

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want to make a simple http server using ktor. However, when I enter the site (127.0.0.1:8080 or 0.0.0.0:8080), it just isn't there. It doesn't print and doesn't respond.
However if I use NanoHttpd instead of ktor, everything works fine. What is my issue?

```
import io.ktor.application.call
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.response.respondText
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty


fun main() {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                println("TEST")
                call.respondText("Hello World!", ContentType.Text.Plain)
            }
        }
    }
    server.start(wait = true)
}
```

The output is just:

```
[main] INFO ktor.application - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
[main] INFO ktor.application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: Could you tell me the OS you're using?

Comment: @Leonid Windows 10. It apparantly works if I switch out Netty with Jetty, now I can't figure out how to to disable logs

Comment: check this address in your browser `localhost:8080`

Comment: @Ramin eghbalian nothing, at least when I am using Netty

Comment: Try to change the port using `application.conf` - https://ktor.io/servers/configuration.html

Comment: Running into the same issue, setting mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.DevelopmentEngine" works

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of the following things:

1. The application code
2. The run configuration

I am leaning towards there being a problem with the run configuration rather than the application code.

### Application code

Even though I think your issue is with the run configuration, in case that it isn't, I'm providing sample code here.

When I use the [IntelliJ Ktor plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10823-ktor), the Ktor app is bootstrapped as follows:

#### Application.kt

```
package com.example

import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello, world!", ContentType.Text.Plain)
        }
    }
}
```

#### application.conf

```
ktor {
    deployment {
        port = 8080
        port = ${?PORT}
    }
    application {
        modules = [ com.example.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }
}
```

I've provided an example Ktor code base here: https://gitlab.com/tinacious/ktor-example

### Run configuration

It could be your run configuration in IntelliJ. It needs to be set up as a Kotlin script (and not an Application). When it's set up as an Application, I get the same error you do. Here is how to set up the run configuration I have, allowing me to run the server in IntelliJ:

1. Add a configuration
2. Choose **Kotlin script** from the Templates section. Do not choose Application.
3. Near the bottom where it says "Use classpath of module" choose your `application.main`.
4. Near the top where it says "Main class" you should be able to choose your main application. I found this only showed up after I chose the classpath of the module.

Here are the relevant sections in the configuration:

[image]

Here is what I describe in step 4, i.e. I can choose my main class after the class path is added:

[image]

The run symbol should be a Kotlin logo:

[image]

I would recommend installing the [IntelliJ Ktor plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10823-ktor) for bootstrapping your project. It uses Gradle and bootstraps everything so when you run `./gradlew run`, you are running it properly and can access it without the manual build configuration step.